# how to check if get Selection contains only whitespace

Tags: javascript

I need to prevent the user from selecting white spaces with get Selection:

```
if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection();
    if (text.rangeCount) {
        if(text==""){return false;}
        var range = text.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
        range.surroundContents(span);
        text.removeAllRanges();
        text.addRange(range);
    }

}
```

My check only returns false if there is no selection at all.

Comment: I can't speak to your situation in specific, but you should be checking if the string is empty *after* you trim leading/trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```
if(text.trim() == "")
```

Comment: Obligatory warning: not supported by IE8 and lower, but you can use a polyfill there.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (text == '')
```

will only ever be true if the text is an empty string.

If you need to match whitespace, you'll either need to trim the text to remove extra whitespace characters, or use a pattern matching regular expression:

```
if (text.trim() === '')
```

or

```
if (/^\s*$/.test(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

window.getSelection() returns a Selection object.

You'll want something more like this:

```
text = window.getSelection().toString().trim();
```

Cheers,

Jesse